# Why an input button created dynamically through a literal tag doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net

I have created button 2 below:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Stop" 

    onclick="alert('hello world');"/> 

<input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" OnClik="alert('hello world');"/>
```

using a litteral tag on page load like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Literal1.Text = "<input id=\"Button2\" type=\"button\" value=\"button\" OnClik=\"alert('hello world');\"/>";

}
```

Incredibly when testing in browser, click on button 1 works, not click on button 2 whereas the codes are the same !

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled onclick for the second button

Comment: Oh my I'm really blind because I checked again and again :)